# How can I read current zoom level of Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I have a back to home function

```
function panToHome(){
    latLng = [current.lat, current.lng];
    map.setView(latLng, 8);
}
```

I want to save the current view as history, so user can switch back as they might click mistakely. So the question is how can I know the current latlng on Mapbox?!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `getZoom` method on your `L.mapbox.map` instance:

> Returns the current zoom of the map view.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getzoom

```
var mapbox = new L.mapbox.map('mapbox', 'mapbox.streets', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 9
});

var zoom = mapbox.getZoom();
```

Here `zoom` holds `9`

Comment: why this reference leafletjs if the question is about mapbox?

Comment: Maybe because the question is about mapboxjs which is based on Leaflet? Even mapboxjs own documentation refers to the leaflet reference. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.3.1/

Answer (score 20):

In Android you can use

```
int currentZoomLevel = mapboxMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
```

Comment: @Moh_beh can you explain what error you get. many people use it and it work. maybe new mapbox version change something. also 1 comment is enough :D

Comment: yes in new version it dosnt work but you can use this

***String me = map.getCameraPosition().toString();***


it return a lot of things include  zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS with Mapbox SDK 4.0, there's a `.zoomLevel` property on the `MGLMapView` object.